# Error from QtCore.so (image not found)

Tags: python, image, pyqt4, qtcore

Running OS X 10.11.2

I am currently trying to run a program called CompuCell3D (website: http://www.compucell3d.org/)

When starting it up I receive the following message

```
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Hello World. Python --version says:
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 
Python 2.7.10
---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- ---- 

 Now starting CompuCell3D 3.7.4  in GUI mode:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Saamic/Downloads/CC3D_3.7.4/player/compucell3d.pyw", line 47, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Saamic/Downloads/CC3D_3.7.4/player/PyQt4/QtCore.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/Deps/QtCore
  Referenced from: /Users/Saamic/Downloads/CC3D_3.7.4/player/PyQt4/QtCore.so
  Reason: image not found
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

What is going wrong here?